# My function is returning segmentation fault error for aparently nothing wrong

Tags: c, data-structures, hash, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I'm making an hashing table data structure and having segmentation fault error on my inicialization function. Here the code:

```
void allocTableSlots(alu **table, int index){
    if(index == MAX)
        return;
    else{
        table[index] = calloc(1, sizeof(alu));
        table[index]->registration = -1;
        table[index]->next = -1;
        allocTableSlots(table, index+1);
    }
}

void initializateHashTable(hash *hashing){
    hashing = calloc(1, sizeof(hash));
    allocTableSlots(hashing->table, 0);
    hashing->collisionArea = 690;
}
```

My structs are these:

```
#define MAX 997

typedef struct alu{
    int registration;
    char name[80];
    char email[80];
    int next;
} alu;
typedef struct reg{
    alu *table[MAX];
    int collisionArea;
}hash;
```

The error comes in:
`if(index == MAX)`
on `allocTableSlots()` function

If I change `MAX`, for `MAX-1`, or any other number, like `500` the error still comes after position `499`, so its not look like that I trying to access an invalid position of my array `table`

I already tried an iterative version (in case that my recursion has some error) but still the same

Comment: Are you missing pointer casting ot that's a typo?

Comment: @Dev-il You don't need to cast `void*` in C. Are you thinking of C++?

Comment: Why does `initializeHashTable` overwrite the pointer that's passed to it instead of initializing the struct it points to?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. But `initializateHashTable` needs to return the pointer it allocates, or it should take a `hash **` parameter.

Comment: I don't recommend using recursion for this. You could get a stack overflow.

Comment: @Barmar has a point. Should the function parameter was `hash **hashing` and the first line was `*hashing = calloc(1, sizeof(hash));`, it would be reasonable but this way, it's a little bit weird.

Comment: `allocTableSlots(hashing->table, 0);` leads to UB.as `hashing->table == NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you most likely should just return the pointer to the allocated block from the init function. Furthermore, if the maximum bucket size is known, as is in your code with `MAX`, the code simplifies to:

```
...
typedef struct reg {
    alu table[MAX];
    int collisionArea;
} hash;

hash *initializateHashTable(void) {
    hash *t = calloc(1, sizeof *t);
    if (!t) return NULL; // check calloc, just in case.
    
    /* Whatever initialization you want to perform. As per your code,
       setting registration and next members to -1 */
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        t->table[i].registration = t->table[i].next = -1;
    }
    t->collisionArea = 690; // EDIT: Forgot the collisionArea
    return t;
}
```

Comment: I saw the comments and the answer that @vmt post and now my function it's fixed and working, thanks to all!